# Is there any method that allow us to go from an activity to Fragment of another activity

Tags: android, fragment

i have an activity having bottom navigation bar and its 5 fragments. and a second activity.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJyJ5.jpg)

is there any method to go from 2nd activity to fragment of 1st activity.

when i use this code

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, new fragment_account ()).commit();
```

**OR**

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new fragment_account ()).commit();
```

then i successfully going from activity to fragment of another activity

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiWZe.jpg)

but problem is that after going on fragment, the bottom navigation bar is hidden. and 2nd problem is:  when successfully going to fragment then want to going from this fragment to another fragment then application crushes.

**After Going from activity To Fragment of another activity**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsANQ.jpg) Bottom Navigation bar is hidden. its a problem

By using **fragment to fragment**

```
fragment_account next = new fragment_account();
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, next, "findThisFragment") 
                            .commit();
```

is there any method to solve this problem?

i tried to go fragment to fragment by this method

```
fragment_account next = new fragment_account();

getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, next, "findThisFragment") 
                            .commit();
```

**Fragment to Activity**

```
Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), activity_name.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Problem is Here **Activity to Fragment**

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, new fragment_account ()).commit();
```

and also

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new fragment_account ()).commit();
```

error is that after going from one activity to fragment of another activity then bottom navigation bar hidden

Comment: You should include some code, xml & screenshots to help describe your problem. What do you mean my navigation bar? The system navigation bar or some sort of navigation bar you made?

Comment: I have Included Screen Shoots of Bottom Navigation bar that i made inside the application

Comment: No any one know?